# Regex issue with grep

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I am trying to write a regex  that will find in CVS(Coma Separate Values) file bunch of phone numbers.

Catch is I am interested only in phone numbers in particular column(as an only after particular amount of comas). Bellow I have regex that will do that and it works fine per Javascript standard.

```
(?:^([^^]*\,){3}[^^]*)\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}
```

I am actually working in Bash and using sed, grep but I cannot even find what Regex standard does grep, and sed use?

Here is sample text.

**note that right now I am using '^' instead of ',' to keep values separated, because users included comas in the value.**)

THIS IS NOT THE ACTUAL DATA, IT IS SCRAMBLED TO PRESERVE PEOPLE'S PRIVACY

```
28434658^17 Three^2013-09-19T19:57:23Z^80 W 54th St, Penthouse & 4th Fl, NY, 10018s212-409-1641^^Mary Szyb 347-340-1918^2 x week Thur 2.5hrs  & Sat 4 hrs
28937693^356 West 36th street^2013-09-19T18:17:57Z^356 West 36th street, suite 706sNew York New York 10018^null^null^on call: 
29219313^333 rector pl^2013-10-07T17:11:36Z^333 Rector Place 248-469-5859^^Jose Hernandez^2 x week Wed & Fri
28854346^50 Can^2013-09-23T13:10:54Z^152 East 28th Street, 7th Floor, NY, 10018s917-932-3962s646-710-4170^155 W 24rd St 3rd FL^null^Swlvia Smith347-933-6630sIrena Brown 347-991-1346s5 x week Mon-Fri
28434698^4Eleven^2013-09-19T19:57:23Z^112 West 28th Street, 3th Fl,sNY, 10018s917-922-3862s646-710-4170^^null^null
```

Let me also clarify one thing correct output would be:

```
212-409-1641
248-469-5859
917-932-3962
646-710-4170
917-922-3862
646-710-4170
```

Because these are the only phone numbers in column 4

Comment: Please provide your input, you might not even need a regular expression here.

Comment: The standard that these commands will use depends on what implementation you are using and which switches you have enabled. You might want to try `grep -Po` (after looking at `man grep`, of course :)

Comment: Don't try to manipulate structured data in an unstructured way.  You're asking for trouble down the road.  What if one of the columns before the one you're interested in is quoted and has a comma inside it?

Comment: @hwnd touche I updated the question

Comment: @AndyLester I agree with you, but the data is still unstructured, I am trying to structure it better, see my update with sample data.

Comment: @TomFenech I started in man pages, and I did try particularly grep -P problem is that per PERL standard {} should include repetition multiplier, but grep returns nothing when it sees it

Comment: @TomFenech I take back what I just said that I repeated the grep -P and I must have done something wrong previously, now I just need to make this work on sed

Comment: Your data is confusing, do you actually have `^` for separation in your file, if not then can you provide the actual data?

Comment: @hwnd your right if you look and the address' you see that users were including comas in the file, I don't want to make a new column becuse of the user entry

Comment: So still my question, is `^` in the actual file used as a delimiter or should I consider every `^` as a comma?

Comment: at least for now until I figure out what to do with user entered comas but that seems to be a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the regex that ended doing the job:

```
([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})(?=[^^]*(\^[^^]*){3}$)
```

thank you everyone for the helpful input

I guess my lesson from that problem is if one solution does not work try to work from different angle, in this case count the columns from the back.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for you.

```
grep -Po '(\d{3}-){2}\d{4}' file.csv
```

**UPDATE:**

After replacing `^` with comma's as they are in you **actual** data..

```
28434658,17 Three,2013-09-19T19:57:23Z,80 W 54th St, Penthouse & 4th Fl, NY, 10018s212-409-1641,Mary Szyb 347-340-1918,2 x week Thur 2.5hrs  & Sat 4 hrs
28937693,356 West 36th street,2013-09-19T18:17:57Z,356 West 36th street, suite 706sNew York New York 10018,null,null,on call: 
29219313,333 rector pl,2013-10-07T17:11:36Z,333 Rector Place 248-469-5859,Jose Hernandez,2 x week Wed & Fri
28854346,50 Can,2013-09-23T13:10:54Z,152 East 28th Street, 7th Floor, NY, 10018s917-932-3962s646-710-4170,155 W24rd St 3rd FL,null,Swlvia Smith347-933-6630sIrena Brown 347-991-1346s5 x week Mon-Fri
28434698,4Eleven,2013-09-19T19:57:23Z,112 West 28th Street, 3th Fl,sNY, 10018s917-922-3862s646-710-4170,null,null
```

You could try the following.

```
perl -nle '@F = split(/,(?!s| )/, $_); print $1 while ($F[3] =~ /((\d{3}-){2}\d{4})/g)' file.csv
```

Output

```
212-409-1641
248-469-5859
917-932-3962
646-710-4170
917-922-3862
646-710-4170
```

Comment: Great this works on gregp for me as well(minus the fact that this ignores column that phone is in), what I am trying to do to finish this is make it work on sed as well, on the bottom of the man page they say they use POSIX regex which doesn't seem to work for me.
I will sed had -P switch :(

Comment: I see you updated your question, and only want the phone numbers from column 4?

Comment: output shows additional numbers which are not shown in the op's desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Grep can use the perl or posix standard with -P or -E.  See *man grep* for details.  For something like this, I normally use *cut* to separate fields first, assuming that none of the fields will ever contain the column delimiter.

```
echo "a,b,c,123-555-1212,d,e,f" | cut -f 4 -d','
```

or from a file,

```
while read line; do
   c4=$(echo $line | cut -f 4 -d',')
done < /tmp/file.csv
```

If any of the columns can contain commas then you're probably better off switching to a CSV library in ruby, python, etc.

UPDATE: using -d'^' to separate columns, you can pretty easily match the columns you're interested in, as above, the tricky part with sed is extracting the phone numbers,

```
f="80 W 54th St, Penthouse & 4th Fl, NY, 10018s212-409-1641"
echo $f | sed -r 's/(.*?)([0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$)/\2/'
212-409-1641
```

Not that you have to use the extended regex sed command line argument (-r) cannot seem to use regex literals like \d{3}.  The documentation for sed is found in the info page, but it's usually easier to grep the net.  This is a pretty good tutorial: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/10/unix-sed-tutorial-advanced-sed-substitution-examples/

Answer (score 0):

An answer using `awk`:

```
awk -F'^' '{ 
  start = 0;
  str = substr($4, start);
  while (match(str, /([0-9]{3})-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}/)) {
    print substr(str, RSTART, RLENGTH);
    start = RSTART + RLENGTH;
    str = substr(str, start);
  }
}' datafile
```

This takes the 4th column, repeatedly matches the phone pattern, and prints it out on a line.